# Newly Uploaded WordPress Theme Not Showing Up In Web Sever

Tags: wordpress, server, ftp, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm new to WordPress. I just successfully installed it on my site.

Now I'm trying to toy with creating my own custom theme. I created one with a custom index.php and a style.css. I zipped the folder, and uploaded it successfully from my WordPress admin by going to `Themes > Appearance > Add New > Upload Theme`, then browsing the zipped file. I activate the newly uploaded theme, and run my site's url, and lo and behold, the new theme gets loaded up in the browser. So far so good.  But then when I look into my wp-content/themes folder in my web server through my ftp client, the newly uploaded theme isn't there. The default themes(twentyfifteen, twentysixteen and twentyseventeed) are all there but not my new theme. What could possibly be happening? Isn't that where the new theme should be?

Is there some crucial step in the installation of WordPress that I may have missed?

On the flip side, if I directly FTP to my new folder into the `wp-content/themes` folder in my web server, it doesn't show up in my `Themes > Appearance` page.

What gives? Please any hints/clues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have navigated to correct wordpress folder in FTP?

Comment: make sure your zipped folder didnt create 2 folders when being unzipped!
ie: themes/newtheme/newtheme/style.css

Comment: @charan kumar what do you mean by the "correct wordpress folder"? In my web sever, I have  all the files and folders from the wordpress package and I went through the installation successfully. So in the root of my server, I have the folders wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, and then a whole bunch of php files including the index, a license txt file, and a readme html file.

Answer (score 0):

To reveal weher is your theme

1. open your site
2. view page source in your browser (ctrl+u)
3. press ctrl+f to find this "wp-content/themes/" in the source
4. next word to "wp-content/themes/" is your loaded theme

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple WordPress installations on a single web server. Are you sure you are FTP'ing in to the correct web directory? Also, make sure you log in with the master credentials.

Comment: Well in the root of my web server, all I have is the files and folders from what I believe would be one word press installation. There is a wp-admin, a wp-content and a wp-includes folder. Then there is an index.php file and a whole bunch of other php files, a readme html file and a license txt file. So if there were other wordpress installations, where could they be possibly hiding?

Comment: It depends on your hosting. If your host provides support, it is best to talk to them as they know their server inside-out.